# Force client to send DHCP options to next-server

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

We currently have clients connecting to a DHCP server when asking for an IP. We then redirect to `next-server` with some additional options.

The next server has a DNSMASQ running that should be able to get all sent options by the DHCP server.

With this current configuration for a specific machine (it does actually go through this condition):

```
if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 20) = "PXEClient:Arch:00007" { # UEFI-64-1
    # user-class has code 77
    option user-class "test";
    next-server nextserver.example;
    # We even tried forcing sending this option, as the client might not be asking for it:
    # 4d is 77 in hex
    option dhcp-parameter-request-list = concat(option dhcp-parameter-request-list,4d);
}
```

When checking all traffic on the next server side we do not see this option at all. The same happens with other options such as `option vendor-class-identifier "PXEClient";`

Is there anything I might be missing? It seems that the client just sends the starting options to DHCP server, then to `next-server`, without taking any of the specified options on the DHCP server configuration.

EDIT: `dnsmasq` configuration

```
bind-interfaces

dhcp-option=vendor:PXEClient,6,2b

dhcp-match=x86PC, option:client-arch, 0
dhcp-option-force=x86PC,211, 30

dhcp-match=BC_EFI, option:client-arch, 7
dhcp-match=X86-64_EFI, option:client-arch, 9
dhcp-match=AARCH64_EFI, option:client-arch, 11

# path refers to server address, this case it is local, as there is a separate tftp server serving these files from /tftpboot/
# Use the tag to differentiate loader
pxe-service=tag:x86PClgcy,x86PC, "netboot x86PClgcy", /test/loader/lgcy/pxelinux
pxe-service=tag:x86PC,x86PC, "netboot x86PC", /test/loader/bios/lpxelinux
pxe-service=tag:BC_EFI,BC_EFI, "netboot BC-EFI", /test/loader/uefi/bootx64.efi
pxe-service=tag:X86-64_EFI,X86-64_EFI, "netboot X86-64_EFI", /test/loader/uefi/bootx64.efi
pxe-service=tag:AARCH64_EFI, 11, "netboot AARCH64_EFI", /test/loader/arm64/bootx64.efi

# ONE pxe-service per tag:architecture only
# for defined pxe-skip-menu=<CSA>
# this requires patched version of dnsmasq
pxe-skip-menu=x86PC
pxe-skip-menu=BC_EFI
pxe-skip-menu=X86-64_EFI
pxe-skip-menu=11


# i.e. it delegates the main DHCP server to allocate the IP
dhcp-range=10.0.0.0,proxy,255.0.0.0
dhcp-range=100.64.0.0,proxy,255.192.0.0
(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using ISC `dhcpd`. From its `dhcpd.conf(5)` man page:

> `next-server server-name;`
>
> The `next-server` statement is used to specify the host address of the server from which the initial boot file (specified in the `filename` statement) is to be loaded.  `Server-name` should be a numeric IP address or a domain name.

Note that the server name indicated by the `next-server` statement is **not** another DHCP server. Classically it might be a TFTP server.

If your client first sends a *DHCP request* to one DHCP server, then to another, it means the client rejected the offer of the first server for some reason. According to DHCP protocol specifications, there is no way for a DHCP client to accept only parts of a DHCP offer; it's all or nothing.

Comment: AFAIU in this case, the DNSMASQ intercepts the request before delegating the TFTP server to provide the bootloader.